# Removing FB App without checking "remove all Activities"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

If people remove an application in their facebook settings they are able to do that without checking "remove all app activities".

[image]

(Screen is german, but the text right to the checkbox says: "Remove all app activities")

Im using this code snippet for authentication:

```
$user = null;
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'MYID',
  'secret' => 'MYSECRET',
  'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if (!$user)
{
   //Request new Authentication, get Permissions and Token
}
else
{
   //Start App
}
```

If someone removed the App **without** checking that option, he can still visit my app and `$user` still contains the user id so no new authentication process is initiated.

But I do really wonder, what exactly is removed if you are not checking that option and if really all my permissions are still there?
Otherwise if not, how can I detect this kind of "light deletion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option only prevents things from being shared on their profile. They have not removed the app entirely, which is why you don't need to re-auth them.

They would need to remove the app from the [App Settings Page](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications). This will remove all access to the user's profile and then you would need to re-auth the user.

Comment: So all permissions are still given? Even the permission to post on their wall? That would be content sharing on their profile after all.

Comment: The checkbox means the user has removed the permission to publish to wall. As this is an app activity.

Comment: Well if a wall post is a must for the process in the app, it is somehow a problem, that the user can alter the permissions, but I guess I will have to detect that change and ask for his permission again :-)

Comment: You can detect which permissions the user has allowed, and then prompt them for it again. Read up on the Facebook documentation.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much, for other people who are stuck at this point here are all methods to get the granted permissions explained: http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-user-has-certian-permission-facebook-api/22/